# Should I create enum or collection for positions?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, collections, enums

I would like to create sample program. 
It will has Department Class,Position Class,Employee Class.

Each department will has any positions. I don't know that how I should specify that.

And I don't use DataBase. It is only to learn OOP in Console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether to use an `Enum` or a `Collection` mainly depends on the following criteria:

- How often you expect the available values of positions to change?
- Who will conduct the changes?
- Does the Position only have an Id and a Text or do you expect it to have other data fields as well.
- Will each position be available once per Department and not several times?

If your answers are

- Seldom.
- The developer.
- Only Id and Text.
- Yes

then an `Enum` with a [FlagsAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a good option. However, if there is any doubt about this, creating a class for a Position and adding a collection  is a better way as it is more flexible. It also allows you to add the same kind of position several times to a Department, if this is a requirement.

Though you don't use a database up to now, also note that adding an `Enum` property to the Department is much easier to save in comparison to have related positions that should go into a separate structure.

---

Based upon your comment, I suggest to add a constructor to set the relevant data in a department upon creation (you might also think about whether the data should be private fields as you could not access them from the outside):

```
class Department 
{ 
    public Department(Dep departmentType, IEnumerable<Position> positions, int employeeCount)
    {
        this.departmentType = departmentType;
        this.positions = new List<Position>(positions);
        this.employeeCount = employeeCount;
    }

    Dep departmentType; 
    List<Position> positions; 
    int employeecount;
}
```

You could then create a new Department like this:

```
var dep = new Department(Dep.Electric, 
                         new Position() [] { new Position(), new Position() }, 
                         5);
```

Please note that you might also need to add a constructor to your Position class. In the above sample, I create two Position objects that are added to the Positions list in the Department.

Comment: Thanks Markus and Bharathram Attiyannan.

I will have  
**class Deparment**
{ Dep departmentType;
List<Position> positions;
int employeecount;}

aslo  **enum Dep**
    {
        Electric , Mechanic , HR , Account 
    }

also **enum Pos** { Boss, Servant, Engineer, AssistantDirector, BranchManager, Secretary}

For example , I would like to make instance of Deparment class.

Deparment D = new Deparment(***How must I enter 3 positions ???***
**strong text**

If question is strange , i am sorry.
I am new in OOP.

Comment: Thansk you very much Markus :)

Comment: @Jeyhun: you're welcome. Good to hear that it helped. Please consider accepting the answer if it was helpful.

Comment: Yeah, It helped me. I wrote my simple program via OOP :)

Answer (score 0):

If position is going to be just string values, its best to have them as enum and write your logic around it.

If new position gets added to the enum, the logic will break and it would help you to write specific functionality for each position.

You can write a class around this position enum to alter its functionality based on the enum.

Comment: Thanks Markus and Bharathram Attiyannan.

I will have  
**class Deparment**
{ Dep departmentType;
List<Position> positions;
int employeecount;}

aslo  **enum Dep**
    {
        Electric , Mechanic , HR , Account 
    }

also **enum Pos** { Boss, Servant, Engineer, AssistantDirector, BranchManager, Secretary}

For example , I would like to make instance of Deparment class.

Deparment D = new Deparment(***How must I enter 3 positions ???***
**strong text**

If question is strange , i am sorry.
I am new in OOP.